# The Probability of an Earthquake Event

Tags: exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I'm looking for ways to to find the probability of an earthquake event from Twitter posts. I came across an equation in a [research article](https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/publication.weblab/2013_Takeshi+Sakaki_IEEE+Transactions+on+Knowledge+and+Data+Engineering_Tweet+analysis+for+realtime+event+detection+and+earthquake+reporting+system+development.pdf) that I need to understand and use. My goal is to write a function $f(n)$ where $n$ is the number of tweets posted during a time period, say 1 hour. These tweets are assumed to describe an earthquake event using some classifier. The research article proposed the following function to compute the probability of earthquake occurrence from $n$.

The equation: $p_{occurance}(t) = 1 - p_{false}^{n_0(1-e^{-\lambda(t+1)})/(1-e^{-\lambda})}$.                  (1)

What I gathered from the [research article](https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/publication.weblab/2013_Takeshi+Sakaki_IEEE+Transactions+on+Knowledge+and+Data+Engineering_Tweet+analysis+for+realtime+event+detection+and+earthquake+reporting+system+development.pdf) section 4.1 are the following:

- $\lambda = 0.34$
- $p_{false} = 0.35$ which is the rate of a tweet being a false-positive meaning it was classified as describing an earthquake but it is not. The value is based on experimental data.
- number of tweets expected at time t is $n_0(1-e^{-\lambda(t+1)})/(1-e^{-\lambda})$
- The distribution is exponential.
- the following is a snippet from the paper. A sensor refer to person reporting (tweeting). A positive signal means a tweet reporting an earthquake.

[image]

### My attempt

I used equation 1 (see above) as follows: I replace $n_0$ with the number of positive tweets at any given period, say 1 hour and got the following results:

[image]

Are these results valid, meaning I used the equation the right way? What is the meaing of $t + 1$ in the equation? I replaced $t + 1$ with only $1$ which has no effect. Is this correct?
I lack some stats background and need to understand this.

Comment: Because $t$ is referred to as "time," then $t+1$ must be a time one unit later than $t.$ One simple way to check your understanding and your calculation is to compute the expected number of sensors *both* ways: that is, using the sum at the left and its formula at the right.  You don't need any stats knowledge to do that.

Comment: When you compute it at 1 hour, you have $t=1$,so then $t+1=2$.